# Logical Operators exhibiting strange behavior

Tags: java, logical-operators

```
if ((File_1[i].ID.equals(File_2[j].ID)) 
&& (File_1[i].Relation.equals(File_2[j].Relation)))
```

The first condition here, `(File_1[i].ID.equals(File_2[j].ID)` shows false when it is supposed to be true. They both have equal values.

Am I doing something wrong? This is unusual.

```
ID: fa001
ID: fa001
```

These are the values of the first 2 variables that are compared, but it shows up as false.

Comment: Print some special characters around the IDs to see if there is some whitespace around them.

Comment: What kind of Object is an ID? Do you need to implement the equals() and hashCode() methods?

Comment: ID: fa001.. I think its a String.

Comment: Yeah, they are all strings. 
La-comadreja, there are whitespaces!

Comment: @user3645570 - Then use. String1.trim().equals(String2.trim()) :)

Comment: @NickJ It's a string and I just found out there are whitespaces after La-comadreja suggested

Comment: @user3645570 OK then. If you need to make it ignore whitespace, then you can do File_1[i].ID.trim().equals(File_2[j].ID.trim())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the TYPE of ID (`int`, `string`, `char[]`, etc) the `.equals` method can do some weird things. Assuming they are strings, try comparing `ID.trim()`, which will remove any witespace around the ID.

Answer (score 3):

The original poster has said the ID is a String type and there are whitespaces around the String.  In order to remove the whitespaces of String s:

```
s = s.trim();
```

However, if ID is a type you have created, make sure you implement the `.hashCode()` method.  From the Javadocs:

> If two objects are equal according to the equals(Object) method, then
>   calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce
>   the same integer result.

Also make sure that `.equals()` is overridden from class Object to allow for your definition of whether the values of your new object type are equal.